# Partition a list of strings with duplicates into different lists with no local duplicates

Tags: python

In python, how can I partition a list of strings into several lists with no duplicates per list, taking as many string as possible in each iteration until every item has been inserted in a list?

Input:

```
["1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "5" ]
```

Output:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
["2", "3"]
["3"]
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Depends on how you would split it. For example, you can just split the list in question into 8 different lists, each list containing 1 element, so there would be no duplicates.

Comment: I'd like as many items as possible in each list until there remain none to sort. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easy way, provided the elements can be used as dict keys:

```
def partition(xs):
    from collections import Counter
    result = []
    c = Counter(xs)
    while c:
        uniq = list(c) # one of each key remaining
        result.append(uniq)
        c -= Counter(uniq) # and remove one of each of those
    return result
```

Then

```
>>> xs = ["1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "5"]
>>> partition(xs)
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3'], ['3']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
def spli(arr):
    l = Counter(arr)
    #find counter object
    k = l.most_common(1)[0][1]
    #find amount of list needed
    l = dict(l)
    final = [[] for _ in range(k)]
    #initialize empty nested lists
    for i in l:
        for k in range(l[i]):

            final[k].append(i)
    print(final)
```

Output:

```
>>> spli(["1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "5" ])
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3'], ['3']]
```